# Existence of the highest weight of a representation of a lie group.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group, $T$ a maximal torus, and $\Delta^+(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})$ a system of positive roots with corresponding simple system $\prod (\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})$. Write $\mathfrak{n}^+= \oplus_{\alpha \in \Delta^+(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})} $$\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ with weight space decomposition $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in \Delta(V)}V_\lambda$.

> Definition: A non zero $v \in V_{\lambda_0}$ is called a highest weight vector of weight $\lambda_0$ with respect to $\Delta^+(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})$ if $\mathfrak{n}^+v=0$, i.e, if $Xv = 0$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{n}^+$.  In this case, $\lambda_0$ is called a highest weight of $V$.

Sepanski in his book compact Lie groups says that such a highest weight $\lambda_0$ exists and  his  proof was given by the following argument:

> Existence of a highest weight $\lambda_0$ follows from the finite dimensionality of $V$ and theorem 6.11.

Theorem 6.11 says that for $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in \Delta(\mathfrak{g}_ \mathbb{C}) \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, $[\mathfrak{g}_\alpha, \mathfrak{g}_\beta] \subset \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha + \beta }$.

I have understood the proof of the above result but I still don't know how to use it with the finite dimensionality of $V$ in order to prove the existence of the highest weight $\lambda_0$.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ has dimension $1$, we can choose some $e_\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ that spans it. (If you don't know this fact, you can take a basis of each eigenspace and the argument goes through.)

Now take a nonzero weight vector $v\in V$ with weight $\lambda$, and do the following: if $e_\alpha v=0$ for every $\alpha$, then $v$ is a highest weight vector and you're done. Otherwise there is some $\alpha_1$ such that $e_{\alpha_1}v\neq 0$. Then replace $v$ by $e_{\alpha_1}v$ and start again.

After $n$ steps you will get some vector $e_{\alpha_n}...e_{\alpha_1}v$, of weight $\lambda +\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n$. Since the $\alpha$'s are positive, these weights are all different for each $n$. However $V$ is finite dimensional, so it has finitely many weight spaces. Therefore this process stops at some point, and so it gives some highest weight vector.

Comment: In other words applying $\mathfrak n^+$ increases the weight so starting from a nonzero vector you must reach zero at some point, and the "penultimate'' vector is then a highest weight vector

Comment: thank you very much @Alvaro for your answer! I have a question, am I right in thinking that we take $v$ to be $e_{\alpha_1}v$ because $e_{\alpha_1}e_{\alpha_1}v=0$ ?( If so then I understand the rest of the proof.)

Comment: Well, rather because the weight of $e_{\alpha_1}v$ now has weight $\lambda+\alpha_1$: if $h\in \mathfrak{h}$, then $he_{\alpha_1}v=e_{\alpha_1}hv+[h,e_{\alpha_1}]v=\lambda(h)e_{\alpha_1}v+\alpha_1(h)e_{\alpha_1}v=(\lambda(h)+\alpha_1(h))v=(\lambda+\alpha_1)(h)v$.

Comment: So you increase the weight by $\alpha_1$, and repeating such a process must end in $0$ because $\mathrm{dim}(V)<\infty$. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes I understand your comments but I don't understand why do you replace  in the 2nd paragraph $v$ by $e_{\alpha_1} v$ ? What is the purpose for doing that ?

Comment: .@Alvaro Martinez could you please explain it to me in the case where we have two simple roots, I'm very confused !

Comment: Sure, basically you want to find some nonzero weight vector $v$ such that $e_\alpha v=0$ for all positive roots $\alpha$. You start with some random nonzero weight vector $v$ and write down a list of all $e_\alpha v$. If all of the new vectors in your list are zero, then you're done because $v$ is a highest weight vector by definition. Otherwise you take one of the vectors in the list and repeat the process. The idea is that this algorithm must terminate because $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: For instance, take $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_3\mathbb{C}$ and $V=\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathbb{C}^3)=\mathbb{C}\cdot\{v_1^2,v_2^2,v_3^2,v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_2v_3\}$, the symmetric square of the natural representation $V=\mathbb{C}\cdot \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. The basis I wrote down is actually a basis of weight vectors, for instance $v_1v_3$ has weight $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_3$, where $\epsilon_i(a_1h_1+a_2h_2+a_3h_3)=a_i$. In fact, the weight vector $v_1^2$, with weight $2\epsilon_1$, is the highest weight vector.

Comment: The proof in this case would be as follows: take some random nonzero weight vector, for instance $v=v_2v_3$. Write $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ for the usual simple roots. Now $e_{\alpha_1}v=E_{12}\cdot v=(e_{\alpha_1}v_2)v_3+v_2(e_{\alpha_1}v_3)=v_1v_3+0=v_1v_3$, of weight $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_3$. This is again not a highest weight vector because $e_{\alpha_2}v_1v_3\neq0$. In fact, $e_{\alpha_2}v_1v_3=v_1v_2$, of weight $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$

Comment: Once again this is not a highest weight vector, but after applying $e_{\alpha_2}$ one more time we actually get $v_1^2$, and you can check each $e_\alpha$ annihilates it, so you're done. If this process didn't actually end, then you would have nonzero weight vectors of higher and higher weights, making $V$ infinite dimensional - a contradiction.

Comment: Many thanks to you @Alvaro Martinez for your helpful comments!